# timesyncd switching NTP servers

Tags: 16.04, desktop-environments, systemd, ntp

Running Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop. Anyone have an idea why timesyncd keeps switching from the NTP server I set with DHCP to ntp.ubuntu.com after a few minutes?

```
-- Logs begin at Sun 2016-08-21 00:17:02 EDT, end at Wed 2016-08-24 21:01:43 EDT. --
Aug 21 09:11:37 portege-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[15762]: Synchronized to time server 192.168.11.1:123 (192.168.11.1).
Aug 21 09:11:56 portege-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[15780]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.91.157:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Aug 21 17:46:08 portege-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[20508]: Synchronized to time server 192.168.11.1:123 (192.168.11.1).
Aug 21 17:51:47 portege-ubuntu systemd-timesyncd[20559]: Synchronized to time server 91.189.89.198:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
```

Comment: `ntp` picks the server it is happiest with. Check `/etc/ntp.conf` on `localhost` and `192.168.11.1`

Comment: I am not using ntp on the localhost. Strictly using the native systemd-timesyncd